# Should I be concerned about these warm, seemingly blackened receptacles in a bedroom?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I am completely renovating a 2 bedroom home, where the two bedrooms are wired together on a single 15amp breaker.

I spent most of the day yesterday painting one bedroom while running a portable AC on max setting in the other bedroom. After I finished painting, I began replacing the electrical components when I observed the following:

1. The receptacle was noticeably warm to the touch (presumably from my 11amp AC running all day on the 15 amp line)
2. ALL of the outlets and switches appeared noticably "blackened" or burnt. Here is a picture of one of the outlets. Ignore the right side that was painted white - I painted over it since I knew I was replacing it. You can see what looks like the original color inside the left prong socket
   [image]
3. Some of the insulation of the neutral wires also appear blackened:
   [image]

Is there something fishy going on with this room that I should be worried about, or is it just the case of some really old outlets going bad? None of the other outlets in the home look like the one pictured above, and presumably they were all installed at the same time.

these are the outlets I am installing
[image]

Comment: There has been some excess heating going on.  Those black marks on the white wires is not good either.  If only low power things like lights/radios were plugged in those outlets I would suspect loose connections.  If something baseboard/space heaters, then there might be a problem in the panel also allowing too much power.  Maybe just someone placed a larger breaker in that they should not have.

Comment: The breaker and the outlets are all 15amp

Comment: Then loose connections is probably the cause.  Follow the answers below.

Comment: Are all the conductors solid copper? Could they be copper coated aluminum? Look at the ends. What looks like discoloration from heat might be something else. Heat discoloration from a loose connection on the receptacle should be highest near the device and decrease moving away. If you had discoloration inches away, then something else is happening. Examine the discolored insulation and see if it is brittle compared to insulation not discolored.

Comment: the front of the outlet is beige plastic, the rest of the receptacle is dark brown ... front has been painted to match ... paint is peeling off

Comment: Also, check the rest of the old outlets in your property.   They may be in a similar condition.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I see a beige receptacle, with a factory black coating which has been worn down by repeated plug insertions, with white paint on it covering the "worn down" telltales on the right side.  Not seeing anything jumping out at me on the receptacle.

On the wires, I see heat stress on two neutrals, but not down their entire length. So this tells me they were pressing against a different wire that was suffering thermal stress. Since backstabs are notorious, it was probably there. Certainly a black wire, since black insulation hides the discoloration.   I would not worry about the neutral wires but wrest/twist out each wire out of the backstab.  Why not just cut with a wire cutter? Because you want to be able to do post-mortem inspection of each wire end for burning, arcing or spalling damage.  Can't do that if you cut.

If you see a wire end with visible arcing/overheat damage, cut it back a little bit until you get to copper less obviously annealed.

Also inspect for any aluminum wire. That's not a problem per se, but will need to be handled special (if we want to apply the lessons of the past so we don't have a problem).

Your receptacle there has 3 wires per side.  That clever receptacle with Wago lever-nuts for terminals seems to support only 2 wires.  Either pigtail, or use the $3 **spec-grade** receptacles which have "screw-and-clamp" feature allowing 2 wires under each screw (so 4 per side).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed analysis! Yes, I was planning to pig-tail the three hots together and the three neutrals together and connect a single pair of wires to the new outlet. I will inspect the ends of each wire as well.

Comment: You don't have to pull resisting wires out of the spring loaded backstabs. There is a release mechanism you insert a tool into (e.g., small flat blade screwdriver) that releases the grip of the spring.

Comment: I'm not seeing that as "factory black coating" at all. For that matter, all the black or brown or gray receptacles I've met were solid plastic of that color on the colored part. That's a homeowner (or teenager) coating on an ivory receptacle from everything I see here. And it was sprayed form the neutral side, evidently.

Answer (score 14):

The "blackened" on the face out the outlet looks more like paint rather than charring, from these pictures. Charring/soot would not normally be so even, especially across the part of the yoke between faces, and does not usually flake off so cleanly, while paint does. If it was spray paint, that might also explain the blackening on the white wire, even though that "looks" more like soot/char than the face of the outlet does in pictures. Smell it - does it smell burnt?

The **backstab wiring** is to be avoided, and often at fault in cases of actual charring and overheated outlets. Don't repeat that mistake. Never use backstabs - back-insert "screw and clamp" is good, (insert wire(s) tighten screw to hold) backstab (poke wire in, won't pull out, nothing to tighten) is bad, despite UL continuing to list the things. Side wires that wrap around the screw (only one wire per screw in that case) are also fine. Torque the screws to specification in either case.

Comment: I was replacing outlets with the "push click" backstab outlets (the kind where there's a tab that comes up, you insert the wire, then the tab pushes down). Are those also to be avoided?

Comment: Seems like "built-in version of a WAGO LeverLock" - probably OK if from a reputable manufacturer. The problem with push-in backstabs is that they depend solely on spring tension (and have a tiny contact area) which the described version should not suffer from.

Comment: Agree 100%: Black spray paint on the front face and white wires. Also, replace the back-stab connections.

Answer (score 6):

When I replaced a problematic receptacle, the damage was not most obvious to the wires, but on the receptacle itself with melting in the back of the receptacle. Some of the wires in the backstab sockets had come loose and had started arcing inside, and causing the breaker to trip repeatedly.

Looking at the front and back of your receptacle, I see no obvious damage, if the wires had started arcing, it obviously had just started, and the black marks you see is not scorching as you imagine. Instead you would see twisting, melting, and yellowing deformations around the places where the wires stab in the back as they heat up.

Unfortunately for most people the heating of the socket is usually the first sign that there is a problem because this kind of damage is not visible from the front regardless, so it is good that you are being proactive. Backstab sockets are notorious I hear for becoming loose and causing problems with age.

[image: Here is the back of the receptacle]

[image: Here is the front of the same receptacle]

As you can see the front damage looks nothing like the black marks on yours. There is some blackening around where the prongs were, and if you had it in your hand, you would notice that there is some physical rounding as well as discoloration of the back of the socket.

Answer (score 3):

I would replace it, with one that does not use backstab connections. Two of the white wires show discoloration, similar to wire that has gotten hot. Connections in these back stab terminations will eventually work loose causing the resistance increases. If there is a load it will start to warm up, more so as it gets older. The wiring is such that even though nothing is plugged into this unit there are feather down the line that probably have a load.

Comment: Right about the backstab. I think the discoloration on the white wires is spray paint from painting the face of the outlet. If it was hot wires it would show closer to the outlet.